# Running ddev with colima in external hard disk or anywhere besides home directory

Tags: ddev, colima

I'm trying to run ddev outside my home directory. Colima is the docker platform. I'm wondering how I am able to make it fully run in an external hard disk.

I've added a Drupal9 site in my external hard disk and ran `ddev config`.

I then started it using `ddev start`.

I tried installing a Drupal site using the following command but got an error:

```bash
$ ddev drush si --site-name="Drupal 9" --account-name="admin" --account-pass="admin"
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/drush": stat /mnt/ddev_config/.global_commands/web/drush: no such file or directory: unknown
Failed to run drush si --site-name=Drupal 9 --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin: exit status 126
```

Is there a way to have ddev fully run in the external hard disk? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colima by default mounts only the home directory. You can make it mount other things in the config file. You'll want to experiment with the `mounts` configuration in colima.yml. The default is:

```
# Colima default behaviour: $HOME and /tmp/colima are mounted as writable.
# Default: []
mounts: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I was able to get it running using the following:

```
$ colima start --cpu 4 --memory 8 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 1.1.1.1 --disk 128 --mount "/Volumes/ExtremeSSD/Projects:w" --mount "~:w"
```

I also needed to do `ddev composer install` instead of doing it in the host so that the permissions are handled correctly otherwise I get binaries inside vendor/bin not executable. I usually do composer install in the host so that it's faster.